# why should I use t2-medium type instance for RDS instead of t2-micro?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Currently we are using t2-medium type instance in RDS and t2-micro type instance for EC2.

I just want to know, why t2-medium type instance instead of t2-micro for RDS and EC2. Also, Should I use t2-medium type instance for EC2 if I am using same type of instance for RDS ?

Also, want to know the use of RAM and CPU credit and etc things (which are provided by instance types) for the RDS and EC2,both. (Ex. What is the requirement of RAM for RDS). So that we can take decision for the required type of instances.(As per the requirement).

I read brief documentation of all the types of instances but it is not that much helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance size and type you pick for your ec2 instance, doesn't have to correlate with the size and type of your rds instance. Each instance size should be chosen based on the workload.

For example, you might have 10's of thousands of people hitting your web server running on ec2, but the web service may only make infrequent and quick queries to an sql database running on RDS - so in this case, the ec2 instance should be larger and powerful, and you might be able to get away with a smaller RDS instance.

Conversely, maybe the ec2 instance gets hardly and traffic, but it does execute complicated, long-running queries in RDS - so in this case, you maybe able to get away with a micro or small ec2 instance running apache (for example), but may need a medium, large or extra large RDS instance in order to support the query workload.

Make your best guess on the size needed for each, and then monitor performance and scale the size up or down once you have a better sense of the workloads of each.